# How Can Phone w/ No Internet Service Get Downloads? (Hacked??)

Tags: phone

I have an LG phone with T-Mobile pre-paid calling services.

The pre-paid plans range in value from like $40 ...$100, etc., but the one I have does not have internet service included/enabled.

Yet, I occasionally see the phone say it has downloaded an update. How is that possible with no internet service on my plan?

Did I get hacked and someone is faking this?

Thanks!

Comment: Were you ever connected to WiFi?

Answer (score 3):

Even if you don't have a plan which includes mobile data your phone has still the physical ability to get these data, both via mobile data or by Wifi. 
Since updates to the phones operating system are usually pushed directly by your telecom provider you don't need a plan with mobile data to receive such updates. And even if you have switched off mobile data completely you are probably still be able to use Wifi.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The thing about WiFi, though, is that my home network is password secured.  I've NEVER (I'm 100% sure if this) entered into the cell phone my house network's password.  

So, then, who's WiFi or internet would the phone be using?  And is the WiFi on my phone like automatically turned on all the time?  If T-Mobile is doing this for legit reasons, then great.  But, I just want to make sure it's not some hacker trying to trick me!!!

Comment: @atrueidiot: If you never used WiFi my guess is that they are doing it through mobile data. Again, you don't need a mobile internet data plan for this since a provider can push the update from inside their internal network.

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor your phone's data usage stats from the settings menu and find out if your updates happened over wifi of GPRS.Go there and see if you used wifi or gprs internet and monitor the amount of traffic each app has used over certain time period.
Go to ; Settings > Networks > mobile data[image]